# NullPointerException : While getting the bitmap from canvas

Tags: android, canvas, custom-view

What I want to acheive : I want to create a custom view i.e circle , now i want that circle to be visible in my activity , that's work cool for me , i had mentioned this class on the activity . What i want when i click on the inflated circle and then touch any where in the device screen then it draw circle .

Idea is that : onTouch of this circle view i should generate bitmap and when user touches then i should fit the Bitmap to the parent layout.

```
 public class CircleIcon extends View {
    private int centerX,centerY;
    private Paint outerCircularPaint,innerCircularPaint;
    private static final int STROKE_WIDTH = 5;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Canvas mCanvas;

    public CircleIcon(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CircleIcon(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CircleIcon(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CircleIcon(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {

        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100,100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        outerCircularPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        outerCircularPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        outerCircularPaint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);

        outerCircularPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        outerCircularPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);
        outerCircularPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.color_black));

        innerCircularPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        innerCircularPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        innerCircularPaint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
        innerCircularPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.white));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        centerX = getMeasuredWidth()/ 2;
        centerY = getMeasuredHeight()/ 2;
        int radius = Math.min(centerX,centerY);
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, outerCircularPaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius-1, innerCircularPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, outerCircularPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        Log.e("called---",""+w);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    }



    public Bitmap getBitmap()
    {
        this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        this.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.getDrawingCache());// here throwing nullpointer exception
        this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        return bmp;
    }
}
```

In the Activity :

```
private void initCustomMarkerBitmap() {
        Bitmap well = circleView.getBitmap();
        Bitmap save = Bitmap.createBitmap(320, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        Canvas now = new Canvas(save);
        now.drawRect(new Rect(0,0,320,480), paint);
        now.drawBitmap(well, new Rect(0,0,well.getWidth(),well.getHeight()), new Rect(0,0,320,480), null);
        this.mCustomDrawableBitmap=save;
        this.mCustomDrawableMarker = new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(this.mCustomDrawableBitmap));
    }
```

Logcat Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:659)
                                                                                        at com.example.amit8.comapanydemo.customicon.CircleIcon.getBitmap(CircleIcon.java:103)
                                                                                        at com.example.amit8.comapanydemo.ui.base.main.MainActivity.initCustomMarkerBitmap(MainActivity.java:218)
                                                                                        at com.example.amit8.comapanydemo.ui.base.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:84)
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
```

Comment: have you initialized your `circularView`? may be its null

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in your `init()` method, then remove it from the `getBitmap()` method.

```
setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

Check if it's working or not.